# Consider an example with two strata for n=300. Suppose optimum allocation is sample sizes of 200 and 100 in the two strata. The approx sample sizes

Tags: sampling, sample-size, stratification

*Consider an example with two strata for n=300. Suppose the optimum allocation requires sample sizes of 200 and 100 in the two strata. The approximate sample sizes actually used are 180 and 120, respectively. Work out the actual increase in variance (not percentage).*

I tried solving this but wont we need Sh = Std Deviation of hth stratum and Wh = Weight of hth stratum to solve this in non percentage terms.